# on kernel-5.4, Function symbol is not output only function address is output at initcall_debug

Tags: linux-kernel, init

on kernel-5.4, Function symbol is not output only  function address is output at initcall_debug

1 Step.
added initcall_debug=1 printk.time=1 to cmdline

2 Step
Boot the device and check the dmesg

kernel-5.4

```
[    0.007250] calling  0xffffffc01009e9ec @ 1
[    0.007377] initcall 0xffffffc01009e9ec returned 0 after 119 usecs
[    0.007382] calling  0xffffffc01009e404 @ 1
[    0.007388] initcall 0xffffffc01009e404 returned 0 after 1 usecs
```

kernel-4.14

```
[    0.014307] calling  spawn_ksoftirqd+0x0/0x5c @ 1
[    0.016416] initcall spawn_ksoftirqd+0x0/0x5c returned 0 after 2053 usecs
[    0.016421] calling  migration_init+0x0/0x74 @ 1
[    0.016426] initcall migration_init+0x0/0x74 returned 0 after 0 usecs
```

initcall code kernel 4.14

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "initcall %pF returned %d after %lld usecs\n", fn, ret, duration);
```

initcall code kernel 5.4

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "initcall %pS returned %d after %lld usecs\n", fn, ret, duration);
```

The difference is just %pF vs %pS

Why kernel 5.4 can not print function symbols?

I have already CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y

Comment: `%pF` and `%pS` do the same thing (`%pf` and `%pF` are deprecated), so there must be some other change.

Comment: I found that below two kernel config affect the result. CONFIG_LTO_CLANG=y
CONFIG_CFI_CLANG=y